# 'p' must be 1-dimensional

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm newbie to reinforcement learning. I'd like to see and understand the code that predicts Kerath's actor critic value, and then run it with some changes.

Example code: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/rl/actor_critic_cartpole.py

x_probs is 2D shape(1,10,10).

I want to get a random int type value x between 0 and max_x -1 based on probability.

Below is the total error.

```
 ValueError
'p' must be 1-dimensional
  File "C:\Users\cglab\Desktop\Match3\Train.py", line 48, in main
    x = np.random.choice(range(max_x), p=np.squeeze(x_probs))
  File "C:\Users\cglab\Desktop\Match3\Train.py", line 124, in <module>
    main(ACTION_TYPE, MAP_PLAYER, MAX_PLAY_PER_STEP, MAX_STEP, N_TILE_TYPE, MAX_X, MAX_Y, MAX_MOVE_PER_PLAY, N_TARGET)
ValueError: 'p' must be 1-dimensional
```

My code

```
class CustomModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_hidden, max_x, max_y, n_tile_type):
        super(CustomModel, self).__init__()
        self.common = layers.Dense(num_hidden, activation="relu")
        self.x_probs = layers.Dense(max_x, activation="softmax")
        self.y_probs = layers.Dense(max_y, activation="softmax")
        self.tile_prob = layers.Dense(n_tile_type, activation="softmax")
        self.critic = layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        common = self.common(inputs)
        x_probs = self.x_probs(common)
        y_probs = self.y_probs(common)
        tile_prob = self.tile_prob(common)
        critic = self.critic(common)

        return [x_probs, y_probs, tile_prob, critic]

max_x = 10
max_y = 10
max_tile_type = 5
model = CustomModel(512, max_x, max_y, max_tile_type)

state = np.full((max_y, max_x), -1)
state = tf.convert_to_tensor(state, dtype=tf.float32)
state = tf.expand_dims(state, 0)

x_probs, y_probs, tile_probs, critic_value = model(state)
x = np.random.choice(max_x, p=np.squeeze(x_probs)) #error
```

How to change my code?

Comment: How do you want it to be converted?  If you just want the 100 values in a row. use `x_probs.reshape(100)`.

Comment: X and Y are the coordinates of a two-dimensional board.
Since x is of type int and is a coordinate, it must be between 0 and max_x - 1. 
However, I don't know how to get the dimensionality down.

Comment: `x_probs.reshape(100)` error.
AttributeError: EagerTensor object has no attribute 'reshape'. 
        If you are looking for numpy-related methods, please run the following:
        from tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops import np_config
        np_config.enable_numpy_behavior().

Comment: Try TF reshape (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape). I mean this in good will, but a quick internet search for "Tensorflow reshape" would have gotten you this result too..

Comment: There is an error in my question.
I don't want a dimensionality down.
I want to get a random int type value x between 0 and max_x -1 based on probability.
And when I put `tf.reshape(x_probs, [-1])` in the code, I get an error that the sum of the probabilities is not 1.
Is there another way to do this?

Comment: "based on probability" doesn't mean anything.  If your question is "how do I generate a vector of random values that sums to 1", then that's what you should ask.  You can do THAT by generating a list of random values and dividing by their sum.